# Using Kentico authentication/authorisation in an external website

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, authorization, kentico

I have a kentico website that users can log into.

I need to build a separate .net website that users can log into from the kentico website.

Ideally users would go to the kentico site, log in, click a link to the .net site which would treat them as authenticated.

How can I achieve this?

Most things that I look at online either says use OpenID in kentico and the external site (which I can't do), or assume I want to change how kentico authenticates users.

Comment: What version of Kentico are you working on?

Answer (score 0):

Using third party authentication could work. The third party authentication would live on the secondary site, and Kentico would query this as a secondary from of authentication. [This thread](http://devnet.kentico.com/Forums/f62/t24184/New-Custom-Security-implementation-Kentico-6.aspx) has a discussion on how to do third party authentication in Kentico 6.

Kentico's new [Security guide wiki](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K7SG/Kentico+7+Security+guide+Home) also has a great [page about external authentication](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K7SG/Managing+external+authentication) which has example code for using third party authentication in Kentico 7.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't want to change Kentico's authentication method.

Comment: @Gavin : Your links for Kentico 7 is directing to Atlasian cloud and which seems restricted - Can you please share those pages / some Example codes anywhere else ?

Comment: Proper links are: https://docs.kentico.com/display/K7SG/Managing+external+authentication

Comment: Thanks for the new link locations. I've updated my answer.